# Pure JavaScript fadeout then load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a fairly simple jQuery snippet that **fades out an element then loads an external PHP page via AJAX** after a button is clicked, and I'm trying to do the same thing using Javascript, so I can avoid using jQuery at all.

jQuery:

```
$(document).on("click", "#button", function () {
    $("#image").fadeOut(580, function () {
        $("#image-wrapper").load("loader.php");
     });

    return false;
});
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function () {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function () {
        if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300) {
            document.getElementById("image").classList.add("fade--out");
            document.getElementById("image-wrapper").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
            console.log("Success");
        } else {
            console.log('Error');
        }
    };

    xhr.open('GET', 'loader.php');
    xhr.send();
});
```

And some CSS:

```
.fade--out {
    opacity: 0;
}

#image {
    transition: opacity 480ms ease 0s;
}
```

So far I  have written that but I can only get the `XMLHttpRequest` to work ok but I can't seem to get the `image` element to fade out before loading the PHP file. How can I get the `image` div to fade out then load the PHP file inside the `imaga-wrapper` div?

Comment: Your original logic is using a delegate event handler, while your new logic is not.  If you are trying to do a straight conversion, that is a discrepency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See comments:

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function (evt) {
  // Because of event delegation, we need to check to see
  // if the source of the event was the button
  if(evt.target.id === "button"){

    // Add a class to the image that changes the opacity to fully
    // transparent, but because of the default image styling, a 
    // CSS transition will do that over the course of 480 milliseconds.
    document.getElementById("image").classList.add("fade--out");
    
    // Once that is done, call the supplied function
    requestAnimationFrame(function(){
       // AJAX Call here
    });
    
  }
});
```

```css
.fade--out {
    opacity: 0;
}

#image {
    transition: opacity 480ms ease 0s;
}
```